# SQL for my requirement?

Tags: mysql

I need a SQL query to list all the customers who have joined in last 6 months.

This is my SQL for that.

```
    select 
    c.company_name,
    c.phone1,
    c.sprovince,
    c.scountry,
    sum(order_total_amount) as amt_sold,
    max(o.order_date) as last_order_date,
    customersince
from
        tbl_company c
join
        tbl_order o
    on c.companyid = o.company_id
where
    c.companytype like 'Customer'
and
    (PERIOD_DIFF(c.customersince,curdate())<6)
group by company_name
order by amt_sold desc
```

Now I need one more or condition so that if there is null in customersince column then I should check the first order of the customer. If it is in last 6 months I should display that user also.

order_date is available in tbl_order table. The first order of the customer is min(order_date) group by customer_id

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you update the customer table, setting customersince = the min(order_date) where customersince is null?  That would allow you to simplify (and greatly speed up) your query, and would also be faster when your database starts to grow.

Comment: @Matt i don't have permissions to do that..:(

Comment: is `GROUP BY company_name` intentional? If you have two different companies with the same name (but different `companyId` s), should their orders be added up?

Comment: that stinks.  I understand, though.  I just find when I start doing some exotic things to solve a problem, that the problem is usually not where I am looking.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  c.company_name,
        c.phone1,
        c.sprovince,
        c.scountry,
        SUM(order_total_amount) as amt_sold,
        MAX(o.order_date) as last_order_date,
        COALESCE(customersince, MIN(o.order_date)) AS customersince
FROM    tbl_order o
JOIN    tbl_company c
ON      c.companyid = o.company_id
WHERE   c.companytype like 'Customer'
        AND (c.customersince >= NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH OR c.customersince IS NULL)
GROUP BY
        companyid
HAVING  customersince >= NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
ORDER BY
        amt_sold DESC
```

Note the double condition on `customersince`: one in the `WHERE` clause, another one in the `HAVING` clause.

If you have an index on `tbl_customer (customersince)`, this index will be used to filter the appropriate records early (and fine-filter them later).

Answer (score 1):

```
PERIOD_DIFF(ifnull(c.customersince, `first_order`),curdate())<6)
```

you should include your table schema, your first order is refer to which table?

Comment: I believe that first order is the first record in `tbl_order`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have mysql to test, but this where clause might work for you:

```
where c.companytype like 'customer' 
and ( 
    (PERIOD_DIFF(c.customersince, curdate())<6)
    OR
    (c.customersince is null AND (PERIOD_DIFF(o.order_date, curdate())<6)
)
```

Also, you will have to add things you don't have in an aggregate function (max, sum, etc) to your group by clause.

Comment: `MySQL` allows to use ungrouped columns in the `SELECT` list.